# how to use grails pagination

Tags: java, grails, pagination, criteria

I'm newbie to grails and I've tried to use the grails pagination Tag found in grails documentation , i have a search form in my index.gsp

i don't know how to pass params.max and params.offset 
i am using only one action index

i have an index action containing the query to list some books :

```
params.max = 10
params.offset = 0
def author=params.author // i get the input search params
def max = 10
def offset = 0
if(params.max){
    max = params.max
}
if(params.offset){
    offset = params.offset
}

def bookPagin=Book.createCriteria().list {      
    eq("author", author)}
    maxResults(max)
    firstResult(offset )
}
```

this is the paginate tag in my index.gsp :

```
 <g:paginate controller="displayBook" action="index" total="${bookPagin.size()}" params="[author:author]"/>
```

now this code displays the first 10 results , but when i click on the second page 
it doesn't take the input author params although i am pasing the author param in the GET request , is there any other solution ?

Comment: The params attribute looks fine to me. You haven't included the rest of your controller method where you set your `model` attributes so maybe check `author` is the correct variable name - I usually use `[author: params.author]`. FYI, you can probably omit the `action` and `controller` attributes if they are the same as the current page (normally they are).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it...

```
def searchString = "${params.author}%"
def searchResults = Book.findAllByAuthorLike(searchString, params) // max, offset automatically handled
def total = Book.countByAuthorLike(searchString)
render (model:[searchResults: searchResults, total: total])
```

in your GSP, iterate over your `searchResults` with:

```
<g:each var="book" in="${searchResults}">...
```

and after that include:

```
 <g:paginate controller="displayBook" action="index" total="${total}"/>
```

Comment: i have to use with criteria because i have more than one search parameter , and in the index action : i am sending objects like authorList [authorList : authorList ]

Comment: in all pagination examples they are sending the params from index action to another action called in g:paginate , but i am using only one action index

Comment: Next time include your actual code. We can only go off what you put in your question